# Programmatically define global session timeout in Java EE/GlassFish/Spring

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, session-timeout

I wanted to know if there's a way to programmatically define a session timeout in Java EE/GlassFish/Spring other than setting it in `web.xml`. I know that you can do it for one session by `event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(interval);`,  but I want to do it for all sessions, including previously created ones.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down the problem, you need to first have a list of all Sessions currently active, then invalidate them.

Java EE doesn't provide a readymade API for listing all sessions, but by adding a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html), you can have a list of all active sessions. i.e. Add the session on `sessionCreated()` to a List, and remove the session on `sessionDestroyed()` from the List.

Once you have done, so, it's merely a task of iterating thru the List to change session properties.

Comment: can i use spring HttpSessionEventPublisher isnted of HttpSessionListener ?

Comment: @user2133558 Sure, if you are using Spring in your app.

Comment: How can i pass the timeout as a parameter to this listener if i want the user to gain the ability to change through an UI. Is there method in java to access a certain listener in question ?

Comment: @user2133558 Once you have the list of sessions, you can always access that list and manipulate sessions as you wish. For that there is no need to pass param to your SessionListener. However, I am not sure why you have such a convoluted requirement .